# compare char* with string macro

Tags: c++, string, strcmp

I have the following code:

```
#define INPUT_FILE "-i"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
     ....
}
```

is there any way in `C++` to compare between strings in `argv[]` and `INPUT_FILE`?
I tried

```
strcmp(argv[1],INPUT_FILE)
```

It compiles but return `false`  each time.

Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`strcmp`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcmp/) returns `0` if there is a match.

Comment: +1 for non-judgmental response, +1 on comment for public self-flagellation

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried printing `argv[1]`? Just to make sure you're comparing the right stuff...

But you also want to check the [semantics of `strcmp`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcmp/): It doesn't test if two strings are the same, it checks which one is bigger than the other. With `0` being "neither".